# Problem with undestanding generics for class and for method

Tags: java, generics

I cant undestand why line `for (Integer integer : genericClass.getList()) {` have compile error "Incompatible types: requried Object, found Integer
return value for getList is concrete and not depends of T

If I change `for (GenericClass genericClass : list) {` to `for (GenericClass<String> genericClass : list) {` error has gone

Why?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<GenericClass<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (GenericClass genericClass : list) {
            for (Integer integer : genericClass.getList()) {
                System.out.println(integer);
            }
        }
    }

    private class GenericClass<T extends String> {
        private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        private List<Integer> getList() {
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no valid reason for `? extends String` since the class is final.

Answer (score 1):

It works because earlier `GenericClass genericClass` is equivalent to `GenericClass<Object>` and Object doesn't extend *String* which is *final*.

Comment: i know it, but cant understand why. i use only getList and this method has another concrete generic

Comment: You even get a compile warning while writing the class `GenericClass`. Could you clarify your comment a bit further? Also, your list is empty and for loop is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your

```
    private List<Integer> getList() {
        return list;
    }
```

Is private, but you are trying to call it anyway, did you override the default if there is any. Else set it to protected or public.

Answer (score 0):

In your first for loop you didn't mentioned type. Try this

```
for (GenericClass<String> genericClass : list) {
    for (Integer integer : genericClass.getList()) {
        System.out.println(integer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line `for (GenericClass genericClass : list) {` gives error because you've declared GenericClass as `private class GenericClass<T extends String>`.

So, whenever you've to create the object of this class you've to declare it as;
 `GenericClass<String> genericClass`. You've to provide the type.